draw arrowhead dimension line pyqt
code purpose:
each line when drawn must have a dimension line paralell to it with two arrowheads(which will be used for labeling the length later)
the problem:
everytime i draw a new line the arrowheads of the previous dimension line gets removed and i cant seem to find a fix for that
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QVBoxLayout, QToolBar, QAction, QWidget, QGraphicsLineItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QColor, QPolygonF, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF, QRectF


class SketchView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        # Set the initial visible area:
        self.visible_area = QRectF(0, -2000, 3000, 2000)  # Initial visible area
        self.setMouseTracking(True)  # Enable mouse tracking

        # Initialize variables for panning and drawing
        self.dragging = False
        self.drawing = False
        self.last_pos = None
        self.start_point = None

        # Drawing mode
        self.drawing_mode = None

        self.lines = []  # List to store the drawn lines

        self.arrowheads = []  # Initialize the arrowheads list to store arrowhead items

        self.line_dimension_map = {}  # Store each line with its related dimension line

        # Temporary lines
        self.temporary_line = None
        self.temporary_dimension_line = None

        self.dimension_line_arrows = {}  # Store dimension lines and their associated arrows

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            if self.drawing_mode and not self.lines:
                # Start the first line freely in drawing mode
                self.start_point = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
                self.drawing = True
            elif self.drawing_mode and self.lines:
                # Drawing continues from the end of the last line
                self.drawing = True
            elif self.drawing_mode is None:
                # Start panning
                self.dragging = True
                self.last_pos = event.pos()
                self.setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.dragging and self.drawing_mode is None:
            # Handle panning when not in drawing mode
            delta = event.pos() - self.last_pos
            self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(
                self.horizontalScrollBar().value() - delta.x())
            self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(
                self.verticalScrollBar().value() - delta.y())
            self.last_pos = event.pos()
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeAllCursor)
        elif self.drawing and self.start_point:
            # Draw a temporary line in drawing mode
            end_point = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            self.drawTemporaryLine(self.start_point, end_point)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            if self.dragging and self.drawing_mode is None:
                # Stop panning
                self.dragging = False
                self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            elif self.drawing:
                # Finalize the current line
                end_point = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
                self.drawLine(self.start_point, end_point)

                # Check if the shape is closed
                if len(self.lines) > 1:
                    first_line_start = self.lines[0].line().p1()
                    if end_point == first_line_start:
                        # Shape is closed
                        self.drawing = False
                        self.drawing_mode = None
                        self.temp_line = None
                        self.update()  # Refresh the view
                        return

                # Automatically start a new line from the current endpoint
                self.start_point = end_point

    def drawTemporaryLine(self, start_point, end_point):
        """
        Draws a temporary line and its dimension line as the user moves the mouse.
        """
        # Remove any existing temporary lines
        if self.temporary_line:
            self.scene.removeItem(self.temporary_line)
            self.temporary_line = None

        if self.temporary_dimension_line:
            self.scene.removeItem(self.temporary_dimension_line)
            self.temporary_dimension_line = None

        # Draw the main temporary line
        temporary_pen = QPen(Qt.black)
        temporary_pen.setStyle(Qt.DashLine)
        temporary_pen.setWidth(10)

        self.temporary_line = self.scene.addLine(
            start_point.x(), start_point.y(), end_point.x(), end_point.y(), temporary_pen)

        # Draw the temporary dimension line
        self.temporary_dimension_line = self.drawDimensionLine(start_point, end_point)

    def drawLine(self, start_point, end_point):
        """
        Draws a permanent line and adds it to the list of drawn lines.
        Calls drawDimensionLine to create a parallel dimension line.
        """
        # Draw the main line
        pen = QPen(Qt.black)
        pen.setWidth(10)
        main_line = self.scene.addLine(
            start_point.x(), start_point.y(), end_point.x(), end_point.y(), pen)
        self.lines.append(main_line)

        # Draw the associated dimension line
        dimension_line = self.drawDimensionLine(start_point, end_point)
        if dimension_line:  # Only store if a valid dimension line is created
            self.line_dimension_map[main_line] = dimension_line
            print('dimension line added to the map')

    def drawArrowHead(self, point, direction, line):
        """
        Draws a proper arrowhead at the given point in the specified direction.
        The arrowhead will be a triangle pointing in the direction of the line.
        """
        arrow_size = 15  # Size of the arrowhead, increase or decrease as needed
        arrow_angle = 30  # Angle of the arrowhead, can be adjusted for appearance

        # Calculate the points for the arrowhead (triangle)
        left = QPointF(point.x() + direction.x() * arrow_size, point.y() + direction.y() * arrow_size)
        right = QPointF(point.x() - direction.x() * arrow_size, point.y() - direction.y() * arrow_size)

        left_angle = QPointF(left.x() + direction.y() * arrow_angle, left.y() - direction.x() * arrow_angle)
        right_angle = QPointF(right.x() + direction.y() * arrow_angle, right.y() - direction.x() * arrow_angle)

        arrow_head = QPolygonF([point, left_angle, right_angle])

        arrow_pen = QPen(Qt.darkGray)
        arrow_pen.setWidth(2)

        # Draw the arrowhead
        arrow_item = self.scene.addPolygon(arrow_head, arrow_pen)

        return arrow_item

    def drawDimensionLine(self, start_point, end_point):
        """
        Draws a parallel dimension line slightly shorter than the main line,
        adds arrowheads at both ends, and ensures previous arrowheads are removed.
        """
        dimension_pen = QPen(Qt.darkGray)
        dimension_pen.setWidth(6)
        offset = 20  # Distance from the main line
        shorter_factor = 0.85  # Dimension line will be slightly shorter

        dx = end_point.x() - start_point.x()
        dy = end_point.y() - start_point.y()
        length = (dx**2 + dy**2)**0.5

        if length == 0:
            return None

        nx = -dy / length
        ny = dx / length

        offset_start = QPointF(start_point.x() + nx * offset, start_point.y() + ny * offset)
        offset_end = QPointF(end_point.x() + nx * offset, end_point.y() + ny * offset)

        mid_x = (offset_start.x() + offset_end.x()) / 2
        mid_y = (offset_start.y() + offset_end.y()) / 2
        dimension_start = QPointF(mid_x + (offset_start.x() - mid_x) * shorter_factor,
                                  mid_y + (offset_start.y() - mid_y) * shorter_factor)
        
        dimension_end = QPointF(mid_x + (offset_end.x() - mid_x) * shorter_factor,
                                mid_y + (offset_end.y() - mid_y) * shorter_factor)

        # Draw the dimension line
        dimension_line = self.scene.addLine(
            dimension_start.x(), dimension_start.y(), dimension_end.x(), dimension_end.y(), dimension_pen)

        # Remove previous arrowheads before adding new ones
        for arrow in self.arrowheads:
            self.scene.removeItem(arrow)
        self.arrowheads.clear()

        # Draw arrowheads at both ends
        direction_start = QPointF(nx, ny)
        direction_end = QPointF(-nx, -ny)
        arrow_start = self.drawArrowHead(dimension_start, direction_start, dimension_line)
        arrow_end = self.drawArrowHead(dimension_end, direction_end, dimension_line)

        self.arrowheads = [arrow_start, arrow_end]

        return dimension_line


    def DrawingMode(self, mode):
        # Set the drawing mode
        if self.drawing_mode == mode:
            self.drawing_mode = None
        else:
            self.drawing_mode = mode
            if mode == "external_wall":
                self.pen_color = Qt.black
                self.pen_width = 15
            elif mode == "internal_wall":
                self.pen_color = Qt.gray
                self.pen_width = 10

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create a central widget
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        # Create a toolbar
        toolbar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(Qt.LeftToolBarArea, toolbar)

        # Add actions to the toolbar
        external_wall_action = QAction("External Wall", self)
        external_wall_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.sketch_view.DrawingMode("external_wall"))
        toolbar.addAction(external_wall_action)

        internal_wall_action = QAction("Internal Wall", self)
        internal_wall_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.sketch_view.DrawingMode("internal_wall"))
        toolbar.addAction(internal_wall_action)


        # Add the QGraphicsView to the layout
        self.sketch_view = SketchView()
        layout.addWidget(self.sketch_view)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.showMaximized()  # Start the program in full screen
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


the part where clears the temporary arrows to have a clean scene is this:
        for arrow in self.arrowheads:
            self.scene.removeItem(arrow)
        self.arrowheads.clear()

and without this part everything will be a mess(if you dont understand what i mean you may as well delete this part and run the code to see)but it seems to also remove the final arrowheads as well,i tried multiple things to keep those final arrows fixed at their position,but it doesnt seem to work,either i mess up something or program crashes completely
forexample:
       for arrow in self.arrowheads:
           if dimension_line:
               break
           else:
               self.scene.removeItem(arrow)
           self.arrowheads.clear()

here im trying to say if a dimension line is completed dont remove the arrow heads accociated to it
i know the fix might be actually simple,but i just cant seem to find it,tell me if you have any ideas-tnx

Sorry but your code is too extended. Please take your time to provide a more appropriate [mre] by removing aspects that are probably not part of the problem (eg: the snap to grid, or the background) because they are just distracting to us.

the functions you need to pay attention are drawArrowhead,drawDimensionLine,and possibly  drawline
the rest u can just ignore,if that helps

Sorry but that's not enough. We should not simply ignore those parts, they shouldn't be there to begin with for the scope of the question: we should be able to focus on the problem, having lots of irrelevant functions in the code is a distraction that makes our "job" unnecessarily more difficult and annoying. Please take your time and do as requested.

ok this is the smallest i could possibly make my code(since there is no snap to grid function anymore the shape will not be closed no matter how hard you try to do it but that doesnt have anything to do with the problem,it just looks bad,thought i let you know)

That's better, the snap to grid is indeed irrelevant, because it's not part of the problem. The cause is that you constantly draw new arrows, instead of reusing them. I cannot write an answer as your code is a bit convoluted, and fixing it would require a lot of time and efforts, but you should consider a more appropriate approach that could possibly use subclasses. For instance, you could use a QGraphicsLineItem subclass that also has child items (its own dimension line and the arrows) and simply update them instead of redrawing things every time.

i fixed it in another way,but thank you
